# string concatenation in a grouping

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table like:

```
ID [Int] | Group [Int] | Material [Char(100)]
1        | 1           | wood
2        | 1           | plastic
3        | 1           | iron
4        | 2           | rubber
```

How to get an output result as:

```
Group | Material
1     | wood/plastic/iron
2     | rubber
```

P.S.: Firebird 2.5.1

I had tried versions:

```
SELECT Group1, SUM(Material)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Group1
```

convert error

```
SELECT T1.Group1,
  ( SELECT Material + ','
    FROM Table1 T2
    WHERE T2.Group1 = T1.Group1
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) AS Material 
FROM Table1 as T1
GROUP BY T1.Group1
```

unknown token FOR

Comment: Did you try a query yourself?

Comment: Yes. "SUM(Material)" - convert error, "FOR XML PATH('')" - unknown token

Comment: you should include that whole query into your post, too, even if (especially because) you failed to write it correctly, after all that is why you are here, aren't you? ;)

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` is SQL Server specific AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the aggregate function [`LIST()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list):

This function has the syntax:

```
LIST ([ALL | DISTINCT] expression [, separator])
```

So for your problem:

```
SELECT "Group", LIST(Material, '/') AS Material
GROUP BY "Group"
```

Note that as `Group` is a reserved word, it needs to be quoted. The order of `LIST` is not deterministic; sometimes you can enforce it by sorting with a subselect or by using `DISTINCT`, but this is not guaranteed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
String lines[] == //each line of your input is as a separate array element

Map<String,List<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

for(String line : lines){
    String[] tokens = line.split("|");
    String group = tokens[1].trim();
    String material = token[2].trim();

    if(!groupMap.containsKey(group)){
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupMap.put(group, values); 
    }

    groupMap.get(group).add(material));
}

//now we have grouped all the materials. print it

//print headers group | material

for(String key : groupMap.keySet()){

    // import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    System.out.println(key + "|" + StringUtils.join(groupMap.get(key), "/");
}
```